# Ajax code causing my code to not run properly, why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am new to web developing and currently working on a module for a school website. I have created one dynamic input field creation module and now I am working on the back-end. The problem is, when I use the code normally then front-end is fine, but when I add some basic AJAX code to make my form submit the data without reloading the page, then the front-end suffers. When I click on ADD button to create new input field, it simply doesn't work.

Here is a sample of my code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>Dynamic Add Input Fields</header>
    <form name="form1" id="form1">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" class="form-control name_list"/></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success" value="ADD"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var i = 1;
        $('#add').click(function () {
            i++;
            $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input id="name" type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control name_list"/></td><td><input type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn_remove" Value="X" /></td></tr>'); 
        });
        $(document).on('click','.btn_remove',function () {
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#row"+button_id+"").remove();
        });

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the AJAX code I am trying to add is here :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    $('#add').click(function () {
        i++;
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input id="name" type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control name_list"/></td><td><input type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn_remove" Value="X" /></td></tr>'); 
    });
    $(document).on('click','.btn_remove',function () {
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#row"+button_id+"").remove();
    });
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"check.php",
            data:$('#form1').serialize(),
            success:function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $('form1')[0].reset();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Action page for php is here :

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','Test2');

    if(!$conn) {
        echo 'Couldn\'t connect to database'.mysqli_error();
    }
    $count = $length = '';
    $length = count($name[]);

    for($count=0 ; $count<$length ; $count++) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `check1` (name) VALUES ('$name[$count]')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if(!$result) {
            echo 'Couldn\'t add data '.$count.mysqli_error();
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

What I simply want to achieve is to create a form in which infinite number of input fields can be created at run time and when the form is submitted then the data is stored in the database without reloading the actual page.
Sorry for mistake (if any) and thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What *does* it do?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  Does the JavaScript code execute at all?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  What specifically happens?

Comment: I have modified the code. Please check

Comment: You've modified the code, but you haven't clarified the problem.  When you debug this, how does it fail?  Nobody here can see what's happening on your computer.  You have to tell us.

Comment: now the problem is with back-end. My php code is not working. I am not much familiar with the php, so there can be silly mistakes. Thanks

Comment: The code and files are exactly same which I am using and it shows ERROR 500, Internal server error

Comment: A 500 Internal Server Error indicates that an error happened on the server.  If it's an error in your PHP code then check your PHP logs.  Turn on PHP error reporting, etc.  You need to find out what the error *is* before you can correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to bind your handler to the form submit, not click. Also, be sure to cancel the default behaviour - to prevent the page from navigating away.

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
      // ...
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```